# Losing data while renaming column's content in data frame in R

Tags: r

I want to rename some lines in my `PitchAccent` column in my data frame `total` with the following command:

```
total$PitchAccent <- sub("!H*","H*", total$PitchAccent)
```

So that `!H*` now become `H*`.

However, when I check for the number of `H*` afterward, it stays the same as before and `!H*`occurrences seem to be gone.
Moreover, now when I do:

```
summary(total$PitchAccent)
```

It doesn't show me:

```
> summary(total$PitchAccent)
  !H*  !H*L    *?   ..H   ..L    H%    H*   H*?   H*L  H*L?  HH*L    L%    L* 
  262  2125     0    25   633     0  2056     0  6122     0     6     0   460 
  L*?   L*H  L*H?  L*HL    no !H*L?  LH*L     L    !H    H!    .L  L*!H L*HL? 
    0  7818     0    53 69569     0     2     1     0     0     1     1     0
```

,but instead just:

```
> summary(total$PitchAccent)
   Length     Class      Mode 
    89134 character character
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically change the level of the factor from !H* to H*

```
total$PitchAccent <- factor(total$PitchAccent)
levels(total$PitchAccent)[ levels(total$PitchAccent) == "!H*" ] <- "H*"
```

Then, if you want it back to character format, cast it as follows.

```
total$PitchAccent <- as.character(total$PitchAccent)
```

With `gsub` or `sub`, you can do this

```
gsub("!H*", "H*", total$PitchAccent, fixed = TRUE )
sub("!H*", "H*", total$PitchAccent, fixed = TRUE )
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason the summary changed is because sub() coerces the input to character. So total$PitchAccent is no longer a factor with different levels, but character. So summary doesn't provide any useful information. Coerce it back to factor with
`total$PitchAccent = as.factor(total$PitchAccent)`

Comment: Be cautious with `factor`. If there was any sane ordering to the levels before coercion, it's gone now. One way to *kind of* address this is store the old levels (`lev <- total$PitchAccent`), supply them to your call to `factor` on the new variable (`total$PitchAccent <- factor(total$PitchAccent, levels=lev)`), then use `droplevels` to get rid of the ones you nixed (`total$PitchAccent <- droplevels(total$PitchAccent)`).